# F# Search Up Data Tree and Update

Tags: f#, tree

UPDATE:

Pavel correctly answered the original question and made me realize I left out an important detail - the search is on the nth parent.  I'm curious if there's a more elegant solution, but at least I got something that works.

```
type searchf = 
        | None of None: unit
        | CountUp of CountUp: int
        | ParentNode of ParentNode: Node

let search (nthParent: int) (tree: Node) (child: Node): Node = 
    if (nthParent = -1) //-1 Top, 0 Current, 1 Parent, 2 Grandparent
    then tree
    else

        let rec f (t: Node): searchf = 

            match t = child with
            | true when nthParent = 0 -> ParentNode t
            | true  -> CountUp nthParent
            | _ -> 

                let foldSubs (acc: searchf) (xy: Node): searchf = 
                    match acc with 
                    | CountUp i -> CountUp i
                    | _ -> f xy

                let acc =
                    match t.ChildNode with
                    | [] -> None ()
                    | x -> x |> List.fold foldSubs (None ())

                match acc with
                | CountUp x when x = 1 -> ParentNode t //parent found in sub list, so this is it
                | CountUp x -> CountUp (x - 1)
                | _ -> acc

        match (f tree) with 
        | ParentNode t -> t
        | _ -> tree
```

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have a small tree, usually 2-5 nodes per branch, max depth of 4. I'm stuck trying to figure out the functional way of searching the tree for a node and returning updated trees.

```
//I'm not opposed to adding a key field, but my tree does not have one naturally.
type Node = { Name: string; ChildNode: Node list; }

let newNode (name: string)(childNode: Node list) = 
    {Name=name; ChildNode=childNode;}

let tree = 
    newNode 
        "Main" [
        newNode "File" [
            newNode "Open" [];
            newNode "Close" [];
            newNode "Print" [
                newNode "Preview" [];
                newNode "Settings" [];
                ]
            ];
        newNode "Edit" [
            newNode "Cut" [];
            newNode "Copy" [];
            newNode "Paste" [];
            newNode "Preferences" [
                newNode "User" [];
                newNode "System" [];
                ]
            ]

        ]

let updateTree (tree: Node ) (oldNode: Node ) (newNode: Node ): Node =
    //??
    tree

let randomNode = tree.ChildNode.[1].ChildNode.[3]
let newRandomNode = { randomNode with Name = "Options"}
let updatedTree = updateTree tree randomNode newRandomNode
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? What specifically are you having trouble with?

Comment: I've tried staring at it all day.  That didn't work.  I tried googling, but it was all btree stuff.  And I'm specifically having a problem doing a search and replace.  I can do it with loops in c#, but the functional approach has eluded me.

Comment: So it's recursion you're struggling with? Have you learned about that yet? If so, you should review the learning material, try it out and if it still doesn't work, come back with what you've tried and a more specific problem. Also, try starting with a simpler data structure like a list instead of a tree. The algorithms will be very similar.

Comment: I can do a simpler data structure: List.map (fun x -> if x = oldNode then newNode else x).  I'm struggling with trees.  And again, I've been searching for a code snippet to study, but I can't find any.  So if you could provide a link or anything useful, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To solve this yourself you need to understand recursion, and implementing `List.map` is a great way to do so. That's the best advice I can give.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example.

```
let rec updateTree tree oldNode newNode =
    if tree = oldNode
    then newNode
    else { tree with ChildNode = [for a in tree.ChildNode -> updateTree a oldNode newNode]}
```

UPD:
With the update of the question here's another solution.
To find nth parent of node you can use something like this.

```
type SearchResult =
    | Failure
    | Incomplete of int
    | Complete of Node

let searchNthParent nthParent node target = 
    if nthParent < 0
    then Complete node
    else 
        // You can just use this function if you 
        // don't need check on nthParent < 0
        let rec inFunc left node target =
            if node = target 
            then
                if left > 0 
                then Incomplete left 
                else Complete node
            else
                let rec iterateWhileFailure f list =
                    match list with
                    | [] -> Failure
                    | h::t ->
                        match f left h target with
                        | Failure -> iterateWhileFailure f t
                        | a -> a

                match iterateWhileFailure inFunc node.ChildNode with
                | Incomplete left when left > 1 -> Incomplete (left - 1)
                | Incomplete _ -> Complete node
                | a -> a

        inFunc nthParent node target
```

Comment: Thank you, that answers this question perfectly.  I was trying something more complicated because my problem is more complicated, but I think I can adapt this.  The actual update happens on the nth parent, but I think if I change "then newNode" to "Some n", I can count backwards as it goes up the call stack.

Comment: Thank you again, Pavel.  I updated the question with something that works.

Comment: @EricP, I updated the answer too. Although I'd use Optional<int> for nthParent instead of checking negative numbers but maybe you have your reasons for this.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  In the actual model, I wanted callers to have an explicit way to state which node they are looking for and made an enum (Top = -1 | Current = 0, Parent=1, GParent = 2, etc.).  Not in love with that either, but we're talking about a max depth of 4 and I can unwrap to an int and use directly in the search.